# FlatList Ref is Incorrect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having an issue with the FlatList component when calling scrollToIndex. Here is how I'm referencing the list.

```
<Modal visible={modal} transparent onRequestClose={this.onClose}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onClose}>
        <View style={overlayStyle}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.picker, pickerStyle]}>
            <FlatList
              ref={(node) => { this.scroll = node; }}
              style={styles.scroll}
              data={data}
              renderItem={this.renderItems}
              getItemLayout={(_, index) => (
                { length: 24, offset: 24 * index, index }
              )}
              initialNumToRender={5}
              // scrollEnabled={visibleItemCount < itemCount}
              contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContainer}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.value}
              automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
              removeClippedSubviews={false}
              indicatorStyle="white"
            />
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Modal>
```

I included the surrounding code in case that would help. But for some reason I get back a different structure than normal with an error that says _scrollRef.scrollToIndex is undefined. When I check the tree and the ref component I seem to get back the right structure of _listRef -> _scrollRef but the contents are of that of a view ref or a textinput ref. Looking something like...

```
blur
context
focus
measure
measureInWindow
measureLayout
props
refs
setNativeProps
state
updater
```

I'm extremely confused on this situation and some insight as to why would be great.

EDIT:
Here is the code for the scrollToIndex. The promise method was recommended by someone in the RN community. I was using just a set timeout previously.

```
const wait = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
        wait.then(() => {
          if (this.mounted) {
            console.log(this.scroll);
            if (this.scroll) {
              this.scroll
                .scrollToIndex({ index: 0, animated: false });
            }

            Animated
              .timing(opacity, {
                duration: animationDuration,
                toValue: 1,
              })
              .start(() => {
                // if (this.mounted && Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                //   this.scroll.flashScrollIndicators();
                // }
              });
          }
        });
```

Comment: You are missing a parentheses on ref prop. Is it a typo or your current code? `ref={(node) => { this.scroll = node; }` should be `ref={(node) => { this.scroll = node; }}`

Comment: Are you calling scrollToIndex after component mounts or in render ?

Comment: Yes, show ur code where u call the method scrollToIndex

Comment: @bennygenel That was a typo on my part. That is not the issue.

Comment: @Fawas After the mounting, I have a tracker for that because I have animations that should play. Along with that I'm using a set timeout to ensure it.